# callouts direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-cd, callout

I m lost with the callouts and the pointers directions I have read [documentation](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.7) unfortunately it was hard to understand for me,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.callouts,arrows.meta,positioning} 
\tikzstyle{sommet}=[circle,draw,thick,fill=RedViolet,draw=white]


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0.05cm,
  note/.style={draw,fill=white,rectangle callout,minimum height=4ex},
  content/.style={draw,fill=white, ellipse, }
 ]

\draw (0,0)[densely dashed,thick,Gray]circle (4cm);
\draw (0,0)[top color=WildStrawberry,bottom color=Orchid,draw=white ]circle (2.5cm) node[text width=2.5cm,align = center,font=\sffamily\bfseries\large]{Unsupervised \\Learning};
\draw [name=A]  (40:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{ \faDotCircle[regular]}} ;
\draw [name=B]  (-40:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{\faDotCircle[regular]}};
\draw [name=C]   (0:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{\faDotCircle[regular]}};
\draw [name=D]  (140:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{\faDotCircle[regular]}};
\draw [name=E]  (220:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{\faDotCircle[regular]}};
\draw [name=F]  (180:4cm) node[]{\Large\textcolor{DarkOrchid1}{\faDotCircle[regular]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**what I m looking to achieve is this :**
[image: desired result]

*Extra : does any one know what's that font used in that picture*

Comment: Do not use `tikzstyle` - it is deprecated for many years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[table, xcdraw, dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.callouts, arrows.meta, positioning} 
\tikzset{
mycallout/.style={
ellipse callout,
minimum height=2cm, minimum width=4cm,
callout pointer arc=20, callout pointer shorten=0.5cm,
align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw[densely dashed, thick, gray] (0,0) circle[radius=4cm];
\fill[top color=WildStrawberry, bottom color=Orchid] (0,0) circle[radius=2.5cm] node[text width=2.5cm, align=center, font=\sffamily\bfseries\large]{Unsupervised\\Learning};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (A) at (40:4)   {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (B) at (-40:4)  {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (C) at (0:4)    {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (D) at (140:4)  {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (E) at (220:4)  {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[DarkOrchid1, font=\Large] (F) at (180:4)  {\faDotCircle[regular]};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(A), mycallout, fill=blue!20] at (30:6.5) {Test\\Testing};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(B), mycallout, fill=blue!30] at (-30:6.5) {Test\\Testing};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(C), mycallout, fill=blue!40] at (0:7) {Test\\Testing};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(D), mycallout, fill=blue!50] at (150:6.5) {Test\\Testing};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(E), mycallout, fill=blue!60] at (-150:6.5) {Test\\Testing};
\node[callout absolute pointer=(F), mycallout, fill=blue!70] at (180:7) {Test\\Testing};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text en colored circles and shapes]

Comment: Very good. I like this.

Answer (score 4):

The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.

The small circles are defined in the key `slices`.

The angle position of the `data` and the `slices` is defined with the keys `data angle pos{list}` and `slices angle pos{list}`.

The style `rectangle callout` is used in the key `data style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\draw[gray!50,dotted,thick] (0,0) circle[radius=1.6];
\wheelchart[
  data=\WCvarB,
  data angle pos{list}={1,0.5,0},
  data style={
    rectangle callout,
    fill=\WCvarA,
    callout absolute pointer={(\WCdataangle:1.8)},
    align=center
  },
  middle=Unsupervised\\Learning,
  middle fill=gray!50,
  radius={1.2}{2},
  slices={
    (0,0) circle[radius=4pt];
    \fill[\WCvarA] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
  },
  slices angle pos{list}={1,0.5,0},
  slices style={white,draw=\WCvarA},
  value=1
]{%
  blue!50/Human\\Sensing,
  blue/Passive\\Beamforming,
  blue!25/Image\\Classification,
  blue!25/Data\\Science,
  blue/Software Detect\\Prediction,
  blue!50/Molecular\\Simulation Data%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice.... +1